# How to manually edit the search providers in Windows Internet Explorer 9

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, malware

On a Windows 7 system, the search provider has been hijacked, and keeps prompting us to change it when Internet Explorer 9 starts up. It brings up the Manage Add ons dialogue, and we can click on any of the providers, but clicking `Set as Default` does nothing. We can delete anything other than the one that is ironically named nothing, and it even does it if I launch Internet Properties without IE9 starting. I then tried to `Reset` all the settings, but it did not change anything.

Where in the registry or on the filesystem does Windows store this data so I can manually remove the entries?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For user-specific search providers, edit this registry key:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes
```

For system-wide search providers, edit this registry key:

```
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\SearchScopes
```

Answer (score 2):

[HijackThis](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/) will detect unauthorized modifications to IE’s search engines (via each of several different methods) and let you revert them easily.

Further, if you know you have malware, run a scan with some malware scanners, including specifically [Spybot](http://www.safer-networking.org/) which can find numerous problems and “innoculate/immunize” IE at both the user and system levels.

Comment: http://www.malwarebytes.org/ works wonders as well.

Comment: Well, yes; there’s also [SUPERAntiSpyware](http://www.superantispyware.com/), [and so on](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/), [and so on](http://superuser.com/questions/14424/how-can-i-make-a-windows-pc-bullet-proof-for-home-users), but I was narrowing it down to this specific issue.